# Tree like data collation in SQL (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, union

I have two tables in my database

```
Table A with columns user_id, free_data, used_data
Table B with columns donor_id, receptor_id, share_data
```

Basically, a user (lets call x) has some data in his account which is represented by his entry in table A. The data is stored in free_data column. He can donate data to any other user (lets call y), which will show up as an entry in Table B. The same amount of data gets deducted from the user x free_data column.

While entry in Table B gets created, an entry in Table A for user y is also created with free_data value equal to share_data. Now user y can give away data to user z & the process continues.

Each user keep using their data & the entry used_data in Table A keeps on adding up to indicate how much data each user has used.

This is like a tree structure where there is a an entry with all the data (root node) who eventually gives data to others who in-turn give data to other nodes.

Now I would like to write an sql query such that, given a node x (id of entry in Table A), I should be able to sum up total data x has given & who all are beneficiaries at multiple level, all of their used_data need to be collated & showed against x.

Basically, I want to collate

1. Overall data x has donated.
2. How much of the donated data from x has been used up.

While the implementation is more graph-like, I am more interested to know if we assume it to be a tree below node x & can come up with a single sql query to be able to get the data I need.

Example

```
Table A
user_id, free_data, used_data
1         50         10
2         30         20
3         20         20

Table B
donor_id, receptor_id, share_data
1          2             30
1          3             20

Total data donated by 1 - 30 + 20 = 50
Total donated data used - 20 + 20 = 40
```

This is just one level where 1 donated to 2 & 3. 2 in turn could donated to 4 & all that data needed to be collated in a bubbled up fashion for calculating the overall donated data usage.

Comment: Sample data with expected results would be helpful

Comment: If you expect this to scale, I suggest you store the "overall data donated" as a separate column in `A`.

Comment: Added an example. @bishop overall donated data calculation is just 1 level deep & going to be straight forward as share_data entry collation just add up & give me that value. The main issue is with to add up used_data for all candidates who eventually have got the data from x. That is going to be a multi level problem.

Comment: What are the rules for counting recursive donations?


A donates 50 to B  
B donates 25 to C  
C donates 25 to B

etc 

( Of course one could look at current free_data and used_data values to determine overflows )

Comment: Do you want the SQL query for this current data architecture? Or are you looking for an architecture which will solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes its possible using a nested set model. There's a book by Joe Celko that describes but if you want to get straight into it there's an [article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) that talks about it. Both the collated data that you need can be retrieved by a single select statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableB where left > some_value1 and right < some_value2
```

[image]

In the above example to get all the child nodes of "Portable Electronics" the query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM Electronics WHERE `left` > 10 and `right` < 19
```

The article describes how the left and right columns should be initialised.

Comment: Sorry - could you elaborate it a bit. This is not a straight forward nesting problem. Table A entries connect to same table entries through table B. Unlike Table A has many Table B has many Table C kind of entries.

Comment: What you are basically looking for is to get all the child nodes of a given node. That child parent relationship is now in Table B. To summarise the article in Table B add 2 columns called 'left' and 'right'. The values for left and right are assigned based on a pre order tree traversal algorithm. To help visualize how the left and right numbers are generated I will add an image from the article in my answer

Comment: I think the case is only applicable in binary tree? but in above case a node can have multiple child nodes.

Comment: See the diagram I posted. It's not a binary tree

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. This is the right architecture for sure which would keep the calculate logic easy over the long run. The way I can think of assimilating this in my current architecture is to have left & right fields in Table B. The only issue with the architecture is - it needs re-numbering when a new Table B entry comes in.

Comment: Yes renumbering would be the issue. If there are more reads than writes then there wouldn't be an issue. Would appreciate if you could mark this as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve your problem now.

Try below query(note that you will have to pass userid at 2 places):

```
SELECT SUM(share_data) as total_donated, sum(used_data) as total_used FROM tablea
LEFT JOIN tableB
ON tableA.user_id = tableB.donor_id
WHERE user_id IN (select  receptor_id as id 
from    (select * from tableb
     order by donor_id, receptor_id) u_sorted,
    (select @pv := '1') initialisation
where   find_in_set(donor_id, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', receptor_id)) OR user_id = 1;
```

Comment: There seems to be a typo here `total_used FROM LEFT JOIN tableB` . Shudn't there be a table name after total_used ?

Comment: No its `total_used FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB`. If you are on small screen try horizontal scroll.
Here is the complete query in one line - `SELECT SUM(tableB.share_data) as total_donated, sum(A.used_data) as total_used FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB INNER JOIN tableA as A ON A.user_id = tableB.receptor_id on tableA.user_id = tableB.donor_id WHERE tableA.user_id = 1`

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. Dint scroll it enough.

Comment: Still trying to make sense of it. I have a feeling that there should be some kind of `group by` somewhere. Dont you think so ?

Comment: It can be, there are number of solutions possible. I don't use group by much so solved it by joins.

Comment: You are right. I think for just one user `user_id = 1`, it is doable without group by. But lets say, if you want to do it for all users, you can achieve it in single query without where clause & with group by.

Comment: Updated the answer with multilevel tree lookup.

Comment: Woh - this seems to be too hard to follow for someone like me. Would you mind sharing some resource to read up specially this @pv stuff you doing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, the following should give you the desired results:

```
SELECT B.donor_id AS donor_id, SUM(A.used_data) AS total_used_data FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.user_id = B.receptor_id GROUP BY B.donor_id;
```