# how can i get the main value from mysql table, if the table has nested records

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table like following,

```
id | name  |parent
---| ---   | --- 
1  |vehicle|0 
2  |car    |1 
3  |test   |0 
4  |maruti |2 
5  |alto   |4 
6  |test2  |3
```

I have category id of 5. now i want the first parent category of the id 5.

first parent category of id 5 is 1 (vehicle)

for this i need to run 4 queries to get that.

For example,

```
public function getParentCategory($catId)
{
        $cat = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select id,parent from category where id=$catId'));

        if ($cat['parent']  == 0) {

            return $cat['id'];

        } else {

            return $this->getParentCategory($cat['id']);
        }
}
```

Now the above function runs 3 times to get the id of first parent of category `alto`

So, Is there any simple way to get the result easier without running the queries recursively ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37288233/267540

Comment: I don't understand what exactly do you want?if yuo have id than  i guess that is primary key than whats the problem?

Comment: Refer to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278551/tree-like-data-collation-in-sql-mysql/39278681#39278681

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: can you show us your architecture

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get all categories from db  and after select current category in php.
Example

```
$categories = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select id,parent from category'));
foreach($categories as $cat){
    $this->categories[$cat['id']][] = $cat;
}
```

select category:

```
public function getParentCategory($catId)
{
    if ($this->categories[$catId]['parent']  == 0) {
        return $this->categories[$catId]['id'];
    } else {
        return $this->getParentCategory($this->categories[$catId]['parent']);
    }
}
```